# How can I replace a portion of a string with asterixs?

Tags: php, regex

Using `preg_replace()`, 
I want to replace a string like this...

```
aaabbbccc => aaa******
cccdddfff => ccc******
234456789 => 234******
12wcced => 12w*****
123cde => 123***
```

How can I do this with `preg_replace()` using regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo substr($string, 0, 3) . str_repeat('*', max(0, strlen($string) - 3));
```

Not quite `preg_replace`, but...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming >= PHP 5.3

```
$str = 'abcdefg';

$str = preg_replace_callback('/^(.{3})(.*)$/', function($matches) {
   return $matches[1] . str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[2]));
}, $str);

echo $str; // abc****
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uUDZjQ).

However, doing this just on strings like your example is better achieved using [Deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776401/replacement-of-this-string-php/5776420#5776420).